# How to make android theme programmatically

Tags: android, android-theme

I need to build a theme using android programming. Is there a class used for building an android theme for mobile (NOT for my application) ??

Comment: if not for your application, for what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot theme the AOSP Android just like that.

You can however write themes for apps like ADW and Go Launcher. This isn't technically theming Android, but you're theming the main launcher app, which is about as good as it gets on stock Android.

Comment: Ok. And how can I theme the main launcher app ??

Comment: Every OEM has a different launcher app. Which one are you talking about? Users can also install 3rd party launchers.

Comment: the main launcher for android API 16

Comment: That cannot be themed by third party apps. You will have to build it from the project source with your customizations to theme it.

Comment: I need a way to make my theme programmatically. I mean changing the default icons for the O.S such as dialler, Settings .. and so on.

Comment: That is supported by very few launchers. ADW and GoLauncher being the only ones with a big enough userbase to be worth your time.